# Using On Error Resume Next with If statements

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, error-handling

Since On Error Resume Next proceeds to the next statement rather than the next line, does anyone have any suggestions as to using it with If statements?

```
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To r
    If dataArray(i,1) <10 Then
        intA = intA + 1
    End If
    If dataArray(i,2) <10 Then intB = intB + 1
    If dataArray(i,2) <10 Then _
        intC = intC + 1: intD = intD + 1
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```

With each style of If statement above, the addition will still be performed in the case of an error, such as element dataArray(i,1) containing text. This could be fixed with error handlers, but that would become messy with multiple If statements. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to achieve ? and where are you getting your error (without using the `On Error Resume Next`). Sometime it's better to trap and handle your errors)

Comment: You can always add an additional test `If Err.Number = 0`, you can also use statements like `Err.Clear` where appropriate. However, you should not count on the `On Error Resume Next` mechanism massively, it is only an exceptional handy "trick" but if you really want to count on it in your code everywhere, you should really reconsider this decision.

Comment: For example, in the code above, if the variable is not guaranteed to be a number, a *good* code should first test it with `IsNumeric` instead of counting on error handling, because the latter is NOT a `flow control` directive.

Comment: @A.S.H; `IsNumeric()` function must be handled consciously. For instance `IsNumeric("1,.23")` would return True... So I use it only when I know I have "sound" data, i.e. either _real_ numbers or texts. Should OP's `dataArray` come from a `range` then a safe way would be _first_ using `SpecialCells()` to filter _number_ cells and _then_ fill the array and manipulate its data

Comment: @user3598756 there's so much to fit in the small comments area. The point is that good code should not count massively on the `resume next` mechanism and do what is due to handle data correctly.

Comment: @A.S.H, I agree and I hadn't countered that part of your comment. More, the `SpecialCells()` approach is right in that direction. I just pointed out a subtle `IsNumeric()` trap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect digit value on specified position of array you dont really need to build bulky error handlers or use GoTo, you can check for `Type` of variable!
So, example:

```
For i = 1 To r
    If IsNumeric(dataArray(i,1)) And Not IsString(dataArray(i,1)) Then
        If dataArray(i,1) <10 Then
            intA = intA + 1
        End If
        If dataArray(i,2) <10 Then intB = intB + 1
        If dataArray(i,2) <10 Then _
            intC = intC + 1: intD = intD + 1
    End If
Next i

Public Function IsString(ByRef var as Variant) as Boolean
    IsString = (TypeName(var) = "String")
End Function
```

As you see, you can check for `IsNumeric` and, since string can be numeric, then explicitly check for `Not IsString`.

Since not only strings can return True from `IsNumeric` function (e.g chars) there's way to modify example and grow your own function!

Links:
[TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278698.aspx), 
[IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445052(v=vs.60).aspx)

A further example (only numbers with one decimal point and allowing strings).
So what's if input looks like:

[image: input]

Example:

```
Sub AcceptOnlyNumbers()
'pass only strings that can be threaten as doubles
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Set rng = Sheets(1).[A1:A8]

    For Each cl In rng
        With cl
        If Not (IsNumeric(.Value2) Or (IsNumeric(Val(.Value2)) And _
            Len(.Value2) = Len(CStr(Val(.Value2))))) And .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
                Debug.Print .Value2, "is filtered"
            Else
                Debug.Print .Value2, "is passed"
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Output:

[image: output]

And after that we can convert string with `CDbl` if decimal is comma or with `Val` if decimal - dot. Feel free to play around with it! For example, if you don't need decimal numbers, you can add another check after this(or, again, build your own - all this only examples, you can check for whole numbers on start):

```
Public Function IsWholeNumber(ByVal expDbl As Double) as Boolean
    IsWholeNumber = (Int(expDbl) = expDbl)
    'or more bulky but ok too: IsWholeNumber = InStr(Str(expDbl), ".") = 0
End Function
```

Note this fact, that in dot-decimal countries `CDbl` works well with dot and my example works different (values with comma are filtered too).

- `Val`, `Str` will always use US settings (dot as decimal).
- `CDbl`, `CStr` will take account of the regional settings.

Links: 
[Val](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx), 
[Writing International Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733561(v=VS.60).aspx)

Comment: `IsNumeric()` Function must be handled _consciously_. For instance `IsNumeric("1,.23")` would return `True`... So I use it only when I know I have "sound" data, i.e. either _real_ numbers or texts

Comment: @user3598756 since there's no data-example and this just a way how it can be done withnout error handlers. But yes, you're right and you give a good addition, but if asker expect things like you mentioned - it easy to take care of them too! And after all, as I mentioned - asker can just start from it, build something own. I think it's more interesting not just copy/paste answers from SO, especially for this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm not saying your approach _won't_ work. I'm just adding a warning about possible drawback and (possibly) both enhance your answer and help people reading it

Comment: @user3598756, I know, no worries, as I said before - good addition and good warning, thank you! And I think that my explanation of "why I such a douchebag" is clear too.

Comment: and after all `"1,.23"` is a string so my answer can take care of this.

Comment: I'm not testing it but wouldn't `TypeName(var)` return the type of `dataArray`?

Comment: @user3598756 AFAIK, there's no type like `dataArray` - check TypeName link. I don't have an Excel (It's saturday, heh), but i just tested it with vbscript with this line `Dim arr: arr = Array(1,2,"1.,3"): msgbox TypeName(arr(2))`

Comment: I mean "wouldn't it return the same type of `dataArray` variable, since `var` variable is taken from it?"

Comment: @user3598756, No, you pass one value from array, not array. If you pass entire array it would be Variant or String() dependent of content of array.

Comment: I'm not making myself understood. but it's not that important by now

Comment: @CommonSense Awesome! I wonder if I might even make a custom function like you did, but checking that the characters are only 0-9 and ".", and allowing only 1 decimal point. Would this make sense? e.g. it would allow for numbers stored in strings to be processed as well

Comment: @Mars Simpson, Sorry for long feedback, weekends, you know. About your message: of course you can make some own function, just put msdn site to favorites. So about your second question (only numbers with one decimal point): In one of my apps there's textbox in which user should provide length(only numbers and one decimal point (comma or dot, comma is default in Europe, except Britain)) and as we know - user can trick us very well and can feed to textbox anything. So I would update my answer with another example of how I dealt with this problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

a *strict* answer to your question is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, intA As Long, intB As Long, intC As Long, intD As Long

    dataArray = Range("A1:D5").Value
    r = UBound(dataArray)
    On Error GoTo SKIP
    For i = 1 To r
        If dataArray(i, 1) < 10 Then intA = intA + 1

        If dataArray(i, 2) < 10 Then
            intB = intB + 1
            intC = intC + 1
            intD = intD + 1
        End If
SKIP:
    Next i
    ' On Error GoTo 0 '<--| you can comment this out being the last statement since upon exiting the default error handling is resumed 

End Sub
```

Comment: Well in the spirit of our discussion in the comments area, but it would be desirable to also include your suggested `SpecialCells` idiom.

Comment: @A.S.H, I'd love to, but it'd be more effective having real data structure to show it on

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks! BTW, doesn't the Err value need to be reset by a Resume statement? I seem to recall reading that without doing so, Err will remain as <>0, meaning that Err can't be triggered and subsequent errors won't be caught.